# convex hull of finite set is compact

Tags: banach-spaces

In a Banach space, is the convex hull of finite set compact?

Comment: The convex hull of a set of $n$ points is the image of the $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ under a continuous function, so yes.

Comment: Mariano: do you want to write this as an answer (community wiki if you wish) so I can vote it up? I think it's slightly more to the point than Pete's answer (no offence, Pete!) which works fine but I think is slightly over-elaborate. To be fair, the same idea underlies both.

Comment: I am also not keen on questions which give little to no indication of (a) why the questioner wants to know (b) what they've tried doing (c) what level they are at.

Comment: @Yemon: I agree so much that I deleted my answer.


Answer (score 17):

Suppose $X$ is your Banach space and let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a finite subset of $X$. Let $$S=\{(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in\mathbb R^n:t_1,\dots,t_n\geq0,\\,t_1+\cdots+t_n=1\}$$ be the *standard simplex* in $\mathbb R^n$. The map $$\phi:(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in S\mapsto t_1x_1+\cdots+t_nx_n\in X$$ is evindently continuous and its image is $\mathrm{conv}\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Since $S$ is compact, so is $\mathrm{conv}\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

Comment: Just to make perfectly clear what is used in the proof: $\phi$ is continuous because $X$ is a topological vector space and $S$ is compact as $X$ is a separated space.

Comment: $S$ is compact because it is closed and bounded in $\mathbb R^n$, rather! :)

Comment: Sorry, misread I thought $S$ was the image.

Answer (score 3):

Of course yes: the n points lie in the finite-dimentional linear subspace generated by themselves (remember that any norm, when restricted to a finite-dimensional linear subspace, gives rise to the same topology on that space).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the convex hull of a sequence of points $(x_n)$ is (relatively) compact when $x_n\rightarrow 0$, and this easily gives a positive answer to your question (but is somewhat overkill).  In fact, a closed convex set K in a Banach space is compact if and only if it's contained in the closed convex hull of a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\rightarrow 0$.  See, for example, Lindenstrauss and Tazfriri, vol I, Proposition 1.e.2.

Comment: Actually, the statement in the question holds for all topological vector spaces, not just Banach spaces. The generalisation here does not apply so widely. I think you need local convexity.